# Direct Update error FAILURE_UNZIPPING

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

We are customizing the DirectUpdate process as in the documentation (https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_customizing_direct_update_ui_android_wp8_ios.html - with a directUpdateCustomListener) but in the onFinish callback the status is FAILURE_UNZIPPING.

I am testing on an Android (5.1.1) emulator.

```
function wlCommonInit(){
    WL.Client.connect({
        onSuccess: function() {
            console.log("Successfully connected to Worklight Server.");
        }, onFailure: function() {
            console.log("Failed connecting to Worklight Server.");
        }
    });
}

var busyInd = new WL.BusyIndicator('content');
var savedDirectUpdateContext = null;
var restartDirectUpdate = function () {
    if (savedDirectUpdateContext != null) {
        savedDirectUpdateContext.start(directUpdateCustomListener); // use saved direct update context to restart direct update
    }
};

var directUpdateCustomListener = {
    onStart: function(totalSize) {
        busyInd.show();
    },
    onProgress: function(status, totalSize, completeSize) {},
    onFinish: function(status) {
        busyInd.hide();
        console.log("[MFP - DirectUpdate] Finish status: " + status);

        var posSuccess = status.indexOf("SUCCESS");
        if (posSuccess > -1) {
            WL.Client.reloadApp();
        } else {
            WL.SimpleDialog.show('Update Failed', 'Press try again button', [{
                text: "Try Again",
                handler: restartDirectUpdate // restart direct update
            }]);
            wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
        }
    }
};

wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.handleDirectUpdate = function(directUpdateData, directUpdateContext) {
    savedDirectUpdateContext = directUpdateContext

            WL.SimpleDialog.show('Update Avalible', 'Press Update button to download the new version!', [{
                text : 'Update',
                handler : function() {
                    directUpdateContext.start(directUpdateCustomListener);
                }
            }, {
                text : 'Cancel',
                handler : function() {
                    wl_directUpdateChallengeHandler.submitFailure();
                }
            }]);
};
```

How can we fix this?

Comment: Provide the implementation and your expected scenario.

Comment: Can you provide the server logs with the corresponding timestamp when the mentioned error has happened?

Comment: Server logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5lxJaDe7iidjhvdGlnTHNzRm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Client logs: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5lxJaDe7iiMURNN2JuMGt5NVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Does direct update work fine , if you do not customize it? Trying to see if the customization is causing the issue

Comment: Yes, it works. Seems that customization is causing the issue.

Comment: ...but not always... The first time worked but the later requests didn't...

Comment: The "failure unzipping" is not showing in the client logs. Do you have up-to-date logs?

Comment: Yes... I guess the log that you need is not sent to the server. I got these from MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\clientlogs\Android\5.1.1\DSV_Driver\1.0. If there is any other place, please let me know and I will send them.

Comment: I got the analytics log from emulator; there is a strange entry - notice the $bytes: {"timestamp":"08-02-2016 11:01:31:7","level":"ANALYTICS","pkg":"wl.resource_request","msg":"InternalRequestSender inbound","threadid":217,"metadata":{"$path":"10.45.4.31:10080\/DSVMobile\/directUpdate\/DSV_Driver\/android\/1.0\/1211666949\/delta\/default","$category":"network","$trackingid":"35fadc26-54ce-4789-b9b0-f993a684e7bb","$type":"response","$time":1454929291796,"$bytes":0,"$class":"com.worklight.wlclient.WLHttpInterceptor","$file":"WLHttpInterceptor.java","$method":"process","$line":146,"$src":"java"}}

Comment: I think I got the log you're interested since I get the error on zip... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5lxJaDe7iiWFR3X2I4c0o4Zms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: And the log without customization (seems the same error): https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_5lxJaDe7iiRmxkNHlKdlNrdTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Something caught my attention in the log: "$exceptionMessage":"www\/default\/zxing\/.classpath". We are using ZXing lib for barcode scanning but I cannot see the connection with the MFP Direct Update.

Comment: Try with that lib. Is it then working?

Comment: Yes, we have the lib in the app already... I was thinking that this lib can influence somehow the MFP direct update unzipping (native) process. I will try to create a simple app. without that lib and see if that is the cause or the MFP has a different issue.

Comment: In a simple app (without the zxing lib) the Direct update works normal (with and without customization).

Comment: Might be worth while to initialize the library at a later stage of the app, perhaps it is interfering with the Direct Update process.

Answer (score 0):

The custom code is working fine without zxing installed. I suggest that you will try the same without this library. If it works, I suspect that it may be initializing or otherwise interfering with the Direct Update process once an update has been received.

Considering loading the library later in the app life cycle and see if this helps.

Comment: How can I do that? I don't load it manually... it's just referenced in the native app (as a library).

Comment: If you can provide your project then open a PMR for the support team to further debug it.